# Out of memory while running on tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, memory, memory-management, gpu

I'm training a model on  gpu RTX3060 with 6GB memory ,

tensorflow 2.4,

cuda 11.0 and cudnn 8.0.4.

I'm facing this problem dispite the fact that I'm using only batchsize=2 ( even 1 fails )

```
-09-18 11:27:14.053184: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1040] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 979.49MiB
2021-09-18 11:27:14.053190: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1042] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 1081081856 memory_limit_: 4963174976 available bytes: 3882093120 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 4294967296
2021-09-18 11:27:14.053200: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1048] Stats: 
Limit:                      4963174976
InUse:                      1027070208
MaxInUse:                   2221276928
NumAllocs:                       73401
MaxAllocSize:               1234173952
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2021-09-18 11:27:14.053218: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:441] **********************************************____**************************************************
2021-09-18 11:27:14.053235: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1763] OP_REQUIRES failed at cwise_ops_common.h:128 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2,128,128,128,16] and type bool on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

I can't solve the problem , I have set

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 

tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

but it doesn't work, I have the necessary memory but it fails to run.
Can somebody help me?

Edit :
I'm using a 3D-Unet model , here is a summary of my model

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 128, 128, 12 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d (Conv3D)                 (None, 128, 128, 128 1312        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv3d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)               (None, 128, 128, 128 6928        dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3D)    (None, 64, 64, 64, 1 0           conv3d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)               (None, 64, 64, 64, 3 13856       max_pooling3d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 64, 64, 64, 3 0           conv3d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)               (None, 64, 64, 64, 3 27680       dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 32, 32, 32, 3 0           conv3d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)               (None, 32, 32, 32, 6 55360       max_pooling3d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 6 0           conv3d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)               (None, 32, 32, 32, 6 110656      dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_2 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 16, 16, 16, 6 0           conv3d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_6 (Conv3D)               (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 221312      max_pooling3d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 0           conv3d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_7 (Conv3D)               (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 442496      dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_3 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 8, 8, 8, 128) 0           conv3d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_8 (Conv3D)               (None, 8, 8, 8, 256) 884992      max_pooling3d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 8, 8, 8, 256) 0           conv3d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_9 (Conv3D)               (None, 8, 8, 8, 256) 1769728     dropout_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose (Conv3DTranspo (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 262272      conv3d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 16, 16, 16, 2 0           conv3d_transpose[0][0]           
                                                                 conv3d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_10 (Conv3D)              (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 884864      concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 0           conv3d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_11 (Conv3D)              (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 442496      dropout_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_1 (Conv3DTrans (None, 32, 32, 32, 6 65600       conv3d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 32, 32, 32, 1 0           conv3d_transpose_1[0][0]         
                                                                 conv3d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_12 (Conv3D)              (None, 32, 32, 32, 6 221248      concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 6 0           conv3d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_13 (Conv3D)              (None, 32, 32, 32, 6 110656      dropout_6[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_2 (Conv3DTrans (None, 64, 64, 64, 3 16416       conv3d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 64, 64, 64, 6 0           conv3d_transpose_2[0][0]         
                                                                 conv3d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_14 (Conv3D)              (None, 64, 64, 64, 3 55328       concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)             (None, 64, 64, 64, 3 0           conv3d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_15 (Conv3D)              (None, 64, 64, 64, 3 27680       dropout_7[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_3 (Conv3DTrans (None, 128, 128, 128 4112        conv3d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv3d_transpose_3[0][0]         
                                                                 conv3d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_16 (Conv3D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 13840       concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)             (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv3d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_17 (Conv3D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 6928        dropout_8[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_18 (Conv3D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 68          conv3d_17[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,645,828
Trainable params: 5,645,828
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Image shape :  (None, 128, 128, 128, 3)
Mask shape :(None, 128, 128, 128, 4)

Comment: How do you know you have the necessary memory? People cannot really help you without more information.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy ah you are right  it is marked that available bytes: 3882093120 and curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 4294967296 , but the limit is only 4.9GB while I have 6GB in my GPU card.Is there some parameter that I need to change to allocate all my 6 GB? . I tried batch size = 1 but it doesn't solve the problem. What kind of extra information can I provide ? I even changed the type of image to float32 from float64 but it didn't work

Comment: To start, what model you are training, input image size, number of parameters, etc. Note that largest free block is zero, memory could be fragmented which could prevent memory allocations from succeeding.

Comment: I'm using a 3D U-NET model with Total params: 5,645,828
Trainable params: 5,645,828
Non-trainable params: 0
Images : (None, 128, 128, 128, 3)
Masks : (None, 128, 128, 128, 4)

Comment: 3D convolutions require a lot more RAM than standard 2D convolutions. If you read the 3D U-Net paper, you can see that it was trained on a Titan X GPU, which has 12 GB of RAM, double of what you have.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial on yt and the guy has le same amount of memory as mine and he managed to train the model. However he didn't show how he trained the model, maybe he trained on cloud or something, it's odd because as indicated normally it only need 4.2GB of allocation to train according to that but whatever thank you for your time Sir !

Comment: Where do you get that only 4.2 GB are  needed for training?

Comment: curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 4294967296 isn't that the amount of memory needed / batch?

Comment: No, you cannot infer that from an OOM, as it happens while a forward or backward pass is happening, there are multiple allocations, not a single one.

Comment: Yeah.. , it looks like I will never be able to train the model, thank you Sir ! Have a nice day